# Как запретить обновление страницы при смене url?

Tags: javascript

Я написал класс для History интерфейса.
Сейчас мне надо запретить обновление страницы при смене url.

Как мне это сделать ?

В  интернете я нашёл метод

```
window.onpopstate
```

Но он у меня не срабатывает.
И в поиске я не нахожу того, что мне требуется.

Comment: "Примечание:, просто вызов history.pushState() или history.replaceState() не вызовет событие popstate. Событие popstate срабатывает только тогда, когда происходят какие то действия в браузере, такие как нажатие кнопки "назад" (или вызов history.back() из JavaScript). Это событие срабатывает только когда пользователь переходит между двумя записями истории одного и того же документа."

Comment: Уточните, какое обновление вы хотите запретить? Изменение данных на ней, или рефреш (программный, клик по стрелке "обновить" в браузере, ctrl+R, F5, или    что еще). Смена урл происходит при помощи history API, я так понимаю.

Comment: Вызвать window.location.href = '/test' вот что бы при переходе к localhost:8000/test
страница не обновлялась.
Я это делал, но в коде не могу найти. И в интернете почему то не нагугливается.

Comment: Вы хотите заставить браузер перейти на другую страницу, но не отображать ее содержимое?

Comment: грубо говоря да. страницы с сервера грузиться будут

Comment: Как вам написали в ответе, изменить адрес в строке без перезагрузки можно только с помощью хистори апи. Но, если вам нужно обработать непосредственный клик по ссылке или жс команду, можно попробовать поколдовать с window.onbeforeunload. Всунуть в обработчик запрет перехода и поменять адрес с помощью хистори апи.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно изменить URL без обновления страницы, то можно использовать методы объекта `history` `pushState` или `replaceState`. [Вот статья на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API).

Следует помнить, что клики по элементам типа `<a></a>` будут обновлять страницу в любом случае, так что нужно не забывать вешать на них событие `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Я в вопросе написал, что я history api  уже написал. Я методы эти все добавил уже. А если я напишу в коде window.location.href = '/test'  как это изменение отследить ?

Comment: @Sergey Если опираться на [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131147/stop-reload-when-using-window-location) с англоязычного stackoverflow, то предотвратить перезагрузку страницы при window.location.href = '/test' -- нельзя. Скорее всего, это можно объяснить тем, что window.location.href, это же всё-таки свойство (а не метод) отвечающее за содержание адресной строки браузера. И нет никаких обзёрвиров, или типа того, чтобы можно было отслеживать его при прямом изменении, а не через методы.

Comment: да. я посмотрел mdn сейчас.
Способ есть конечно. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Этот listener позволяет отменить изменения, при этом можно путь поменять.
Минус такого способа в том, что из соображений безопасности выводится сообщение в котором пользователь явно должен указать, что он не хочет уходить со страницы.