# Как влиять на ссылку в адресной строке только что открытой вкладки

Tags: javascript, html

Есть страничка со ссылкой, ссылка работает как `window.open(link,"_blank")`. В новой вкладке отображается весь URL из Link.
Каким образом я могу изменить этот URL уже после загрузки новой вкладки? Или, возможно, хотя бы как-то ее скрыть.

Пробовал window.location.href переопределить, но он меняет только ссылку на основной страничке

Comment: ну по готовности той страницы, запустить там сценарий изменения урл..

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал и получилось. Разобрался с тем, как обратиться к этому окошку - поймал ссылку из window.open. Не знал, что так можно, возникла следующая проблема - страничка обновляется с новой ссылкой , и, соответственно, дает 404 ошибку, так как вид ссылки нужен "кастомный".  Аналогичный вопрос -(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1332409/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5-url)
Закрыто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.open` возвращает ссылку на новую вкладку, с которой можно работать. Соответственно, дальше остается изменить `location.href`. Возможно, возникнет проблема с обновлением вкладки, после данного изменения. Для решения этого вопроса стоит обратиться уже к ([Как запретить обновление страницы при смене url?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1332409/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5-url)).